# Location of Emacs' installation

Tags: install

Where is Emacs installed by default on Ubuntu? I need to find its path so I can use it on another application. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Emacs 24.

Comment: No, you don't need to find its path, and you should not do it. If you want to invoke Emacs from another application, just run the command `emacs`. That will run Emacs, wherever it's installed. The way to run an application is through the [PATH variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), and typing a command without any directory name looks it up via this variable. Let this happen, otherwise your application won't work correctly if someone has installed a different version of Emacs in a different location.

Comment: @Gilles I need to use it as an external editor and the application asks for its path.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this question? I mean really! I just ask a simple clear question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Executing the command `which emacs` in your terminal should tell you where it is installed.

Comment: Thanks. Just edit your question and include that this is a terminal command not one that should be used in Emacs.